# How to install Rails through a proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was trying to install Ruby on Rails onto my PC, when I got this error:

```
gem install rails - ERROR: While executing gem (Net::HTTPServerException) 407 “Proxy Authentication Required” [on hold]
```

I tried:

```
gem install --http-proxy http://{domain}%5C{username}:{password}@{proxy.address}:{port}/ rails
```

got the error in the title

I also tried:

```
gem install -p http://pynewbie:mypassword@the-proxy-host.com:8888 rails
```

and got the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name(https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", what happened exactly? Add that information into the question as if it'd been there all along.

Comment: Did you try setting an environment variable `HTTP_PROXY`, that has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

better to use proxychains to proxy all requests inside your command:

```
proxychains gem install rails
```

**after install you have to create configuration file on `~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf`**

[proxychains github](https://github.com/haad/proxychains)

Comment: I don't know what to do with this file. Could you help me

Comment: at the end of the file all type of samples are existing in comments. uncomment and fill them with your values.